# clojure.main not found when running app in docker container

Tags: docker, heroku, clojure

I have the following Dockerfile in my clojure+clojurescript project:

```
# We will use Ubuntu for our image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Updating Ubuntu packages

ARG CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION=1.10.1.507


RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl wget bzip2 openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && curl -o install-clojure https://download.clojure.org/install/linux-install-${CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION}.sh \
    && chmod +x install-clojure \
    && ./install-clojure && rm install-clojure \
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && mv lein /usr/bin \
    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes


ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN conda create -n pyclj python=3.6 && conda install -n pyclj numpy mxnet

## To install pip packages into the pyclj environment do
RUN conda run -n pyclj python3 -mpip install numpy

RUN java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.application
```

But when I push this to heroku, and try going to my app, I get the error:

"clojure.main not found."

When I try building and running this container locally, I get the same error.
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

--- EDIT ---

```
(ns myapp.application
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
            [myapp.components.server-info :refer [server-info]]
            [system.components.endpoint :refer [new-endpoint]]
            [system.components.handler :refer [new-handler]]
            [system.components.middleware :refer [new-middleware]]
            [system.components.aleph :refer [new-web-server]]
            [myapp.config :refer [config]]
            [myapp.routes :refer [home-routes]]))

(defn app-system [config]
  (component/system-map
   :routes     (new-endpoint home-routes)
   :middleware (new-middleware {:middleware (:middleware config)})
   :handler    (-> (new-handler :router :bidi
                    )
                   (component/using [:routes :middleware]))
   :http       (-> (new-web-server (:http-port config) :handler)
                   (component/using [:handler]))
   :server-info (server-info (:http-port config))))

(defn -main [& _]
  (let [config (config)]
    (-> config
        app-system
        component/start)))
```

Comment: that really depends on what is in `myapp.jar`

Comment: target/myapp.jar doesn't exist locally for me.

Comment: Can't say about on heroku. But this same command does deploy the app correctly when I put it in the Procfile.

Comment: I have put what's in myapp.application for you. I couldn't find target/myapp.jar

Comment: I assume myapp.jar is an uber-jar? If so, does it contain all the clojure classes (i.e. clojure itself). There needs to be an entry clojure/main in there.

Comment: There's no myapp.jar in my whole project locally. I can't find the project folder on heroku itself. So I don't know how to check for clojure.main

Comment: well there's a good chance it doesn't even exist. I see you are installing clojure and lein, but there's nothing in there that actually builds something that would produce the myapp.jar

Comment: produce the image, run it interactively and ssh into it. Check if your instructions actually produce the myapp.jar. There's nothing in there that downloads myapp.jar or compiles it from some source code

Comment: I added the command \ && lein uberjar in the Dockerfile right after that conda clean --all --yes, and when pushing to heroku, I get:
"Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for uberjar."

Even though obviously project.clj is there.

And I was able to create myapp.jar using lein uberjar locally.

Comment: The full error is:
"Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for uberjar. The command '/bin/sh -c lein uberjar' returned a non-zero code: 1        "

Comment: And I can't really find the project's root directory on heroku. find . -name "myapp" lists a handful of directories (none of which are myapp) along with "permission denied"

Comment: yeah, nothing in those RUN commands downloads any source code

Comment: what command do I use to download the source code?

Comment: I am using git heroku push master to deploy on heroku, so the source code should be pushed, right?

Comment: but that's two different things! One is deploying a docker image, the other is using git push. You can't have it both ways

Comment: if you do git push, your Procfile does all the building and stuff

Comment: Okay, so adding the command COPY . . also copies the source code. But when the app is deployed, it runs of localhost:5000 on remote and the app doesn't run.

Comment: simplify your approach: build the container and run it yourself, check if the app is working.

Comment: next step: make sure you use the PORT env variable correctly: https://help.heroku.com/PPBPA231/how-do-i-use-the-port-environment-variable-in-container-based-apps

Comment: Using this command:
RUN java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.application --server.port=$PORT --server.host=0.0.0.0
gives:
"Started myapp on http://localhost:5000" on heroku.
and the app crashes.

Comment: Doing `docker build -t test .` locally gives `Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /target/myapp.jar: no space left on device`